# Undo -Werror for a particular warning

Tags: c++, c, gcc, clang, icc

I use `-Werror ... -Wno-unknown-pragmas` compiler flags (cause I don't need unknown pragmas to cause an error).

However, this silences all unknown pragma warnings.

Is there a way to produce `-Wunknown-pragmas` warnings while not turning them into errors, and to apply `-Werror` to all other warnings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`-Werror -Wno-error=unknown-pragmas` should do the trick.